# .NET MySql ArgumentNullException on Open in GetCustomAttributes

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mariadb

I'm trying to swap database providers out in .NET code to MariaDB. As part of that, I'm trying to open a MySqlConnection. This in turn results in an argument null execption with a message of: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: element" and the following call stack:

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(System.Reflection.Assembly element, System.Type attributeType, bool inherit) Line 756 C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(System.Reflection.Assembly element, System.Type attributeType, bool inherit) Line 814  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute<System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute>(System.Reflection.Assembly element) Line 27 C#
>   MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs.InitFramework() Unknown
    MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs.MySqlConnectAttrs() Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.SetConnectAttrs()    Unknown
    MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(bool reset) Unknown
    MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(string authMethod, bool reset)  Unknown
    MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()   Unknown
    MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() Unknown
    MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)   Unknown
    MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.Failover.FailoverManager.AttemptConnection(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection, string originalConnectionString, out string connectionString, bool mySqlPoolManager)    Unknown
    MySql.Data.dll!MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()    Unknown
(My code below this point)
```

I'm using a connection string similar to:

`<add name="MyMariaDatabase" connectionString="server=myservername.rds.amazonaws.com;port=3306; database=mydb;uid=myuser; pwd=mypassword" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`

Sample connection code:

```cs
using (var client = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
     client.Open();
     var result = client.ExecuteScalar(someSqlStatement);
}
```

This is all running in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and MySQL.Data 8.0.19.

Any idea what's going wrong? The error seems deep inside the framework and it's not giving me helpful information.

Comment: Please show us your connection code , there seems to be something wrong with it

Comment: Edit made. Included near bottom.

Comment: Given the depth of the stack-trace I don't think your code is the cause - so I'm inclined to say this is likely a bug in the `MySql.Data.dll` library you're using.

Comment: That was my thought as well. It's possible it's also reflecting my entire assembly set and finding some obscure class somewhere and choking on it. I'm going to try a stand-alone app on Monday as well as downgrading the version. It's weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encountering [bug 95242](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95242), a known problem in Oracle's MySQL Connector/NET (aka `MySql.Data`).

I would recommend switching to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), an OSS MySQL and MariaDB client library. As well as [fixing many bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs) in Connector/NET and adding true async I/O support, it is independent of Oracle so it has support for MariaDB-specific features such as the GSSAPI authentication plugin and [batch support](https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysql-batch/).

Comment: Actually, you may just be catching a first-chance exception; if you let it go unhandled, your program should continue running. I would still recommend switching to MySqlConnector, all the same.

Comment: I think you were both right. I switched to MySqlConnector as recommended and I got additional error details. While SQL Server was fine with different capitalization for database, table, and column names, MySql / MariaDB required the exact capitalization of the database name and errored without additional details using MySql.Data library, but gave me a meaningful "no database" message under MySqlConnector.

Comment: Capitalization rules depend on what OS you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Your Port must be seperated by semicolon.

Instead of

```
"server=myservername.rds.amazonaws.com,3306; database=mydb;uid=myuser; pwd=mypassword"
```

use this Connenction string

```
"Server=myservername.rds.amazonaws.com;Port=3306;Database=mydb;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypassword;"
```

Comment: Thanks. I corrected that issue and the problem still exists with the same characteristics and stack trace. Edited original post to include the new connection string port.

Comment: set constr as the string above ,. I hope. you don't throw the hole thing to the connection